# Send email from ASP.NET Core 6.0 with SendGrid Email API

Tags: c#, sendgrid-api-v3

I have a problem sending an email with SendGrid. I am getting this error:
`Unknown HOST exception (api.sendgrid.com)` in Visual Studio.

I am trying out **SendGrid** and followed their sample code:

```
using SendGrid;
using SendGrid.Helpers.Mail;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Example
{
    internal class Example
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            Execute().Wait();
        }

        static async Task Execute()
        {
            var apiKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("NAME_OF_THE_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_FOR_YOUR_SENDGRID_KEY");
            var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
            var from = new EmailAddress("test@example.com", "Example User");
            var subject = "Sending with SendGrid is Fun";
            var to = new EmailAddress("test@example.com", "Example User");
            var plainTextContent = "and easy to do anywhere, even with C#";
            var htmlContent = "<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with C#</strong>";
            var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, subject, plainTextContent, htmlContent);
            var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

This produced this error:

```
Unknown HOST exception (api.sendgrid.com)
```

I tried to see if I can connect to SendGrid web and api subdomain by pinging it and realized that I was not connecting.

Now I am wondering how to allow my environment to connect to **SendGrid API**. See attachment for my ping result.

If you have faced this issue and solved it, please advice me how you did it.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Your machine is able to resolve the host, it gets an IP address when you ping it. A host doesn't have to respond to ping requests. Do you run the code from the same machine as the ping command?

Comment: Why have you blanked out the IP addresses in your screenshot? They're public info. Anyone can get the same info by running the same commands.

Comment: @CodeCaster: I do not understand. A ping to api.sendgrid.com should return a response such as timeout, TTL,... at least to verify connection. But mine is timed out. Do you suggest a solution?

Comment: It does return a timeout, because the host doesn't respond to pings. That does not mean it's unreachable. They just have the ICMP port firewalled off, or disabled ping responses in their OS, or both. That host does listen on port 443, so you can talk HTTPS to it. Again: do you run your code from the same host (and user) that you do your pings from? Perhaps on your corporate network your IIS user doesn't have permissions to do a DNS lookup, or whatever.

Comment: @CodeCaster: I see. I appreciate your input. Will have to trail options. Thank you.